# Django: Annotating Sum() of two columns in different tables

Tags: python, django

Assuming I have the following models - **How can I annotate the total posting and total story reach of each influencer in my queryset?**

```
class Influencer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Posting(models.Model):
    influencer = models.ForeignKey(Influencer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reach = models.IntegerField()

class Story(models.Model):
    influencer = models.ForeignKey(Influencer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reach = models.IntegerField()
```

I have tried this:

```
queryset = Influencer.objects.all()
queryset = queryset.annotate(posting_reach=Sum("posting__reach"))
queryset = queryset.annotate(story_reach=Sum("story__reach"))
```

However, the values are not calculated correctly using this approach (I assume because of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which is made by `Sum()`). How would I do this in Django?

Comment: Can you give us some why you're saying it's not calculating correctly? Also, please use `print(queryset.query)` and include that. That may give us some more insight.

Comment: Try with distinct=True inside of count or write Subquery expressions
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations

Comment: @iklinac: this will not per se work. For example if there are *two* `Posting`s with the *same* number of `reach`, then you only count these once.

Comment: @schillingt: because of the two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, the two will act as a *multiplier* fo each other, since each related `Story` will be repeated for each related `Posting` and vice versa.

Comment: Not sure how exactly distinct inside of count is implemented, so you are probably right  nice workaround without having to use subquery

Comment: @iklinac: normally the fact that this is count is not relevant, it works normally as `COUNT(DISTINCT posting.reach)`, so it first goes through a uniqness filter before passing it to the count. The sum does not "know" that it is counting distinct values. It is done as "preprocessing" before handing over the set of values to the `COUNT` aggregate.

Comment: Yes you are right, buzzed around a bit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will indeed not work, because your query will make two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s:

```
SELECT influencer.*, SUM(posting.reach), SUM(story.reach)
FROM influencer
LEFT OUTER JOIN posting ON posting.influencer_id = influencer.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN story ON story.influencer_id = influencer.id
```

the two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s will thus act as a multiplier of each other, and thus the sum of `posting.reach` will be multiplied by the number of related `story`s, and vice versa.

A trick could be to divide it by the number of items of the other relation, so:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

queryset = Influencer.objects.annotate(
    posting_reach=Sum('posting__reach') / Coalesce(Count('story'), Value(1)),
    story_reach=Sum('story__reach') / Coalesce(Count('posting'), Value(1))
)
```

Comment: okay that could work, but to be honest: that does not look very "pythonic"

Comment: @RaideR: an alternative is with a `Subquery`, but that will introduce even more "noise".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in a subquery solution:

```
from django.db.models import (OuterRef, Subquery, Sum, IntegerField)

subs = {
    'posting_reach': Posting.objects.filter(influencer=OuterRef('pk')),
    'story_reach': Story.objects.filter(influencer=OuterRef('pk')),
}
qs = Influencer.objects.annotate(
    **{key: Subquery(
            sub_q.annotate(sum=Sum('reach')).values('sum'),
            output_field=IntegerField()
        ) for key, sub_q in subs
    }
)
```